# SOLR DataImportHanlder (DIH) Full Indexing - sometimes our index shows near-zero documents during import

Tags: solr, dih

We're running SOLR 7.2.1.
We periodically update our index (full re-index) via DataImportHanlder (with clear=true).

Most of the time, the normal number of documents in our index (typically around 250,000) remain visible while DIH is running (because it does not commit until the end of the import).

Intermittently, however, we have an issue where the index will suddenly show only a small subset of the documents (maybe 20,000 of them, for example).

I have not been able to track down the source of this, but I do have a suspicion as to the cause:   If someone modifies a product in our website admin area, that will trigger an update to SOLR for that document (with a commit).  Is it possible that this commit, by a separate process, will then cause the partially completed DIH data to also be commited?  If so, that would explain why we sometimes end up with a smaller subset of documents in the index.  When the DIH completes, then the document count returns to normal.

So, do overlapping commits affect each other? In other words, is a commit "global", or does it only affect the data being changed in the current process?

I'd appreciate any clarification on this.

Thanks!

Bill

Comment: Note:  I think I can answer my own question, but I'll wait for verification from people more in-the-know than I am.   In my test environment, while running DIH, if I add another document (with commit=true) from another process, then I do see that the index is updated and the current number of documents that DIH was finished processing at that time is now what is publicly available in the index.  

So, the next question is, can SOLR stop external processes from committing updates to SOLR while DIH is running?   I suspect not, other than by changing the other procs, but it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are not isolated in Solr - a commit or a rollback will affect all documents queued for the index, and not just those that belong to the thread. This is what you've discovered yourself, and the commit that is issued while DIH is working behind the scenes is what's happening.

The way around this is usually to drop the use of DIH, and instead index all documents yourself. That will give you complete control over the indexing process. I'd try to avoid having to remove all documents from the index when starting as well - and if possible, track the deleted documents (and delete them as they're removed in the web interface) and do an extra bulk delete later (if you suspect they've not been removed for some reason).

Another option is to perform the DIH operation on a separate index, then use a [collection alias to swap](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-createalias) where the searched collection points after indexing has completed. This allows you to do the complete index to a separate collection, and when it has finished, swap the current one for the new one and start serving queries from the one you just built.

Be aware that if you are changing the underlying data while indexing through DIH, and rely on the direct Solr update to go through, you'll end up with the wrong data in the index, as the direct update will be performed against a different collection / index.

My choice would be to try to keep the Solr collection in sync with your database, without having to use DIH - and instead rely on direct updates going through. You can then use `commitWithin` to allow multiple threads to add documents, without having to issue explicit commits in either thread.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh,
Our site is based on a shopping cart solution (on PHP) which does have some modules for indexing SOLR itself, but it is very inefficient (takes 2+ hours to run, vs: 3 minutes via DIH).  Someday I may build a custom indexing system myself with another language (not PHP).  For now, DIH is my best option, but I was not aware of the "collection alias" idea. I like that. 
I will continue to explore a custom indexer, but I'm also going to experiment with the collection alias idea.
Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing inherent slow with using PHP to push updates to Solr. You'll likely want to use a message queue, for example something based on RabbitMQ, Apache Kafka or similar, with a function that accepts a list of id's to fetch from the database and push to Solr. Be sure to batch as many documents as possible into a single HTTP POST. We usually see <1s update time for 1k docs depending in complexity and server load, and your total index size is on the smaller side, so it should be rather efficient.